# ¿Cómo validar un e-mail en Java sin usar expresiones regulares?

Tags: java, email, validación

Tiene que cumplir estos requisitos:

- Longitud.
- Sólo puede tener una `@`.
- Saber dónde está la `@`.
- Separar el dominio y el local.
- Que ninguno de los dos sea nulo.
- Local no puede contener `()[];:><` y espacio.
- El local no puede acabar en `.`

Esto es lo que hice/intente yo:

```
public boolean validarEmail(String email, int min, int max){
  //Se definen las varibles tipo boolean
  boolean valido = false;
  //Se definen las variables tipo int
  int posArroba;
  int posPunto;
  //Se definen las variables tipo String
  String local;
  String dominio;
  //Se define el array tipo char
  char [] caracteres = {'(', ')', '[', ']', '\\',',', ';',':', '<', '>', ' '};
  //Condición que me valida la longitud
  if (validarLongitud(email, min, max) == true){
    //Comprobación de que tenemos una @
    posArroba = email.indexOf('@');
    //Condición para que halla una @
    if (posArroba != -1){
      //Definimos los dos conjuntos(variables) para diferenciarlos: local y dominio
      local = email.substring(0,posArroba);
      dominio= email.substring(posArroba + 1,email.length());
      //Condición para que local y dominio no sean nulos, es decir, tengan más de un carácter
      if(local.length()> 0 && dominio.length() > 0){
        //Definimos una variables de la ultima posición
        posPunto = local.lastIndexOf('.');
        //Condición para que esa posición no sea '.'
        if(posPunto == -1){
          //Bucle con el array superior para imponer la condición de que no se encuentre ningun caracter de los antriores
          for (int i = 0; i < local.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < caracteres.length; j++) {
              if(local.charAt(i)!= caracteres[j]){
                valido = true;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return valido;
}
}
```

Comment: Cuéntenos ¿Qué Intentó?

Comment: ¿Podrías publicar tu código? De esa manera podríamos partir de él para explicarte qué modificaciones debes hacer y explicarte el motivo por el que no funcionaba. Te dejo un enlace a cómo crear un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Gracias.

Comment: Te dejo una respuesta que encontré hace tiempo, aunque por desgracia para mi caso no valía, [Respuesta a la pregunta: "What is the best Java email address validation method?

"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5931718/7064040), es un método del paquete oficial del email de java.

Comment: Pero porque? Si con expresiones regulares esto se puede hacer menos lod e saber donde está la @, eso no entiendo bien lo que quieres decir, la verdad.

Comment: Si no quieres topes de cabeza con JS, usa HTML 5 y el input de tipo email

Comment: @Lorthas también podrías saber perfectamente la posición de la `@`

Answer (score 1):

La única forma que se me ocurre aunque es bastante mala, ya que lo ideal es utilizar expresiones regulares es :

```
boolean validar(int tam,string correo)
{
    int pos=0;
    string dominio;
    string local="";

    if(correo.length()<tam){
        if(StringUtils.countMatches(correo, "@")==1)
        {
            pos = correo.indexOf("@");
            dominio = correo.substring(pos+1,0);
            local = correo.substring(pos+1,correo.length());

            if(dominio!="" && local!="")
            {
                if(local[local.length()]!=".")
                {
                    boolean caracteres=false;
                    if(local.indexOf("(")!=-1) caracteres = true;
                    if(local.indexOf(")")!=-1) caracteres = true;
                    if(local.indexOf("[")!=-1) caracteres = true;
                    if(local.indexOf("]")!=-1) caracteres = true;
                    if(local.indexOf(";")!=-1) caracteres = true;
                    if(local.indexOf(":")!=-1) caracteres = true;
                    if(local.indexOf("<")!=-1) caracteres = true;
                    if(local.indexOf(">")!=-1) caracteres = true;

                    if(!caracteres)
                        return true;    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Por favor no respondias a preguntas en las que el OP no haya intentado nada.

Comment: Aunque sea buena tu intencion, no es recomendable responder a preguntas de baja calidad, por lo general estas acaban siendo cerradas. No solo eso si no que muchas veces el mismo autor de la pregunta, cogera tu codigo, no te votara positivo ni aceptara tu respuesta por lo que tu esfuerzo no habra valido la pena.